# Computing the fundamental group of a flag variety

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, lie-groups, homotopy-theory, fundamental-group

Let $G$ be a compact and connected and simply connected Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ be its Lie algebra and $x\in\mathfrak{g}^*$. How can we compute the fundamental group of $G/G_x$  where $G_x$ is the isotropy group of $G$. i.e. $\pi_1(G/G_x)=?$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is that $\pi_1(G/G_x)=0$. Use the long-exact sequence of homotopy groups one obtains from a fibration. In this case, the fibration is $G_x\rightarrow G\rightarrow G/G_x$. We have $$\ldots\rightarrow\pi_1(G)\rightarrow\pi_1(G/G_x)\rightarrow\pi_0(G_x)\rightarrow\pi_0(G)\rightarrow\ldots.$$ Since $G$ is connected and simply-connected, $\pi_1(G)=0=\pi_0(G).$ By exactness, $\pi_1(G/G_x)=\pi_0(G_x)$. However, $G_x$ is always connected, so $\pi_1(G/G_x)=0$. (A reference for the connectedness of $G_x$ is Section 2.3 of "Symplectic Fibrations and Multiplicity Diagrams" by Guillemin.)

Another approach would be to realize $G/G_x$ as a homogeneous space of the complexification $G_{\mathbb{C}}$. We would have $G/G_x=G_{\mathbb{C}}/P$, where $P\subseteq G_{\mathbb{C}}$ is a parabolic subgroup. The Bruhat decomposition of $G_{\mathbb{C}}/P$ involves cells in even-dimensions only, meaning that $\pi_1(G_{\mathbb{C}}/P)=0$.

Comment: Thanks, is there any method for computing $\pi_0(G_x)$? in simplest case $G_x=T$

Comment: Yes, $T$ is connected, so $\pi_0(T)=0$.

Comment: Thanks, what about  $\pi_0(G_x)$ can we say anything about it?

Comment: It turns out that $\pi_0(G_x)=0$. I have added a reference.

Comment: Dear Peter, In the case when $G$ is not simply connected then we still have $\pi_1(G_{\mathbb{C}}/P)=0$ or not?

Comment: Yes. If G is compact and connected, then $G_{\mathbb{C}}/P$ still has the Bruhat decomposition into even-dimensional cells. So, everything works in the same way.